# Can't read the segmentedcontroll index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have implemented several of UISegmentedControl objects before but for one or other reason I am unable to implement it within a tableview cell. I want the user to choose his gender. if the value of the segmentedControl changed a method gets called to save it for further processing.

```
self.seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Man",@"Female", nil]];
[self.seg addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleGender) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I created the method:

```
-(void)toggleGender{
    NSLog(@"%d",self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex)
    if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
         NSLog(@"User is a man");
    } else if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {    NSLog(@"User is a female");
    }
}
```

The first NSLog prints -1 as value if the value has changed.

I declared seg in the header file, and created a property and synthesized it!
I am currently NOT dealllocing this object. (I know this is a memory leak)

Why am I unable to read-out the selected segment, and why does it give back -1 as selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
self.seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Man",@"Female", nil]];
[self.seg addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleGender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

**(NOTE THE ':' in the @selector..)**. And change your function by this :

```
-(void)toggleGender:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",[(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex]);
        if ([(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"User is a man");
        }
        else if ([(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"User is a female");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for one or other reason it doesn't check if the sender is kind of UISegmentControl class, since I get errors on sender.selectedSegmentIndex... Weird stuff

Comment: @AlexvanRijs : my mistake, please see my updated code. Needed to cast 'sender' to UISegmentedControl

Comment: Great! Note that, if the 'toggleGender:' function is called only through an UISegmentedControl, you can remove the test 'isKindOfClass:', to improve speed.